# Message source not found .properties file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot MVC project I have 'messages_en.properties' and 'messages_uk.properties' under 'resources' folder.
Message source configuration:

```
@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    return new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.messages.basename=messages
```

And what I get instead of messages in templates is something like:

> ??contact.email_en_US??

Earlier it worked fine even without configuration(just with messagess bundle placed in the same folder). Maybe the problem is something related to locale?

Comment: I trhink you should rename messages_en.properties or messages_uk.properties (depends on your country local) to message.properties. You must have at least a default file.